# Unable to find an entry point named xxx in mixed C++ DLL and WPF C# project

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dll, dllimport

I am trying to mixing C++ DLL with WPF C# code. My DLL called Transcoder.dll and has simple interface:

> Transcoder.h

```
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)

namespace MathLibrary
{
    class Functions
    {
    public:
        // Returns a + b  
        static MATHLIBRARY_API double Add(double a, double b);

        // Returns a * b  
        static MATHLIBRARY_API double Multiply(double a, double b);

        // Returns a + (a * b)  
        static MATHLIBRARY_API double AddMultiply(double a, double b);

    };
};
```

DLL using `.def` file (added in `Linker->Input->Module Definition File`):

```
LIBRARY
EXPORTS
MathLibraryFunctionsAdd = ?Add@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z
MathLibraryFunctionsAddMultiply = ?AddMultiply@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z
MathLibraryFunctionsMultiply = ?Multiply@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z
```

and my simple C# WPF class:

```
class MathLibrary
{
    [DllImport("Transcoder.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "MathLibraryFunctionsAdd", ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = true)]
    static extern public double Add(double a, double b);

    [DllImport("Transcoder.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "MathLibraryFunctionsAddMultiply", ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = true)]
    static extern public double AddMultiply(double a, double b);

    [DllImport("Transcoder.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "MathLibraryFunctionsMultiply", ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = true)]
    static extern public double Multiply(double a, double b);
}

....

private async void Button_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
   var result = MathLibrary.Add(2.0, 3.0);
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Once I call the `MathLibrary.Add` function. I get:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'MathLibraryFunctionsAdd' in DLL 'Transcoder.dll'.'
```

Output of dumpbin.exe /exports .\Transcoder.dll:

```
File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for Transcoder.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           3 number of functions
           3 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 0001110E MathLibraryFunctionsAdd = @ILT+265(?Add@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z)
          2    1 00011136 MathLibraryFunctionsAddMultiply = @ILT+305(?AddMultiply@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z)
          3    2 00011208 MathLibraryFunctionsMultiply = @ILT+515(?Multiply@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no error here. It didn't work because of a faulty build step that copied the DLL into the application directory. The question above can serve as a template for how to map a C++ DLL to a C# WPF application.